# C++ optimal graph representation for prims algorithm (without boost)

Tags: c++, prims-algorithm

I am looking for a good representation of a Graph for Prim's algorithm.

e.g. to represent a graph for BFS

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::queue<int> > gr;
```

is elegant and concise, it maps each vertex to a queue of neighbours.

For Dijkstra it's a little more complex (weights are in the representation)

```
typedef std::pair<int, double> to_weighted_edge;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<to_weighted_edge> > gr;
```

- use of a priority queue.

If a similar structure is to be follows in Prim's algorithm however, the source of each edge would need to be stored as well and if the graph is represented like:

```
typedef std::pair < std::pair<int,int>, double> from_to_weighted_edge;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<from_to_weighted_edge> > gr;
```

then there is redundant info stored (the source/from vertex).

Any suggestions for what would be the optimal graph representation in C++ for Prim's algorithm are welcome!

ps: one could of course represent the graph as `std::vector<from_to_weighted_edge>` but then there wouldn't be an O(1) lookup of neighbors, which is a common characteristic of all common graph representations.

Comment: checkout this link. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-2/

Comment: Why specifically don't you want to use boost? I smell homework

Comment: the geeksforgeeks links uses an adjacency matrix, while I look for something adj-list like. It's also C-like.

Comment: I don't want boost, because if we are to delegate it all to boost graph libraries the question would be pointless.